# Realsense SDK draw 3D scanning boundaries

Tags: c++, realsense

I am writing a c++ app for 3D scanning. I'd like to add modify the image i get from

```
PXCImage* image = scanner->AcquirePreviewImage();
```

or directly the QImage i create from

```
QImage* qimage = new QImage(imageData.planes[0], width, height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

to display the rectangle which represent the scanned area as in the image below (taken from the c# example).

[image]

I am probably just missing some understanding of the SDK, but I'd be grateful if someone could explain it to me. 
(I am using the PXC3DScan::ScanningMode::VARIABLE if that could affect the process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from Intel:

> It will not support to draw scan boundary when you selected variable scan mode. We will provide this feature in the future release. Thanks!

(Current SDK version 7.0.23.8048)